# Custom first person controller acting strangely

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've been having some trouble making a first person controller and I'm not exactly sure how it works, but basically when you look up at all and try looking to the side some wacky things start happening. If you look up or down at all the camera does a loop-de-loop when you look to either side of the starting position. I added the cube to help show where the camera should be looking and at these points the camera completely disconnects from it and I have no idea why.

this is the most recent thing I tried

````
//two names for the same thing
let lat = 0
let lookHeight = 0
//cube setup
const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(.1,.1,.1);
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xff0000});
const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
cube.position.z = -1
scene.add(cube)
function lookAt(yaw) {
    //cool variable naming, right? It's called ohYeah because vector commits crimes with both direction and magnitude
    const ohYeah = new THREE.Vector3()
    //get the previous camera y rotation before updating
    const prevRotY = camera.rotation.y
    //calculate directly in front of the camera
    const x = Math.sin(-camera.rotation.y)
    const z = Math.cos(-camera.rotation.y)
    //set the vector3 x and z to in front of the camera
    ohYeah.z = z
    ohYeah.x = x
    // set the y of where the camera should be looking
    ohYeah.y = camera.position.y - yaw
    lat = ohYeah.y
    //previous thing I used for debugging
    //console.log("X: " + x + " Y: " + ohYeah.y + " Z: " + z)
    camera.lookAt(ohYeah)
    //set the camera's y rotation back to the previous
    camera.rotation.y = prevRotY
    // set the cube position to where the camera should be looking
    cube.position.x = ohYeah.x
    cube.position.y = ohYeah.y
    cube.position.z = ohYeah.z
    //make the cube face look at the camera
    cube.rotation.y = -camera.rotation.y

}
function getTarget(yaw) {
    const target = new THREE.Vector3()
    const x = Math.sin(-camera.rotation.y)
    const z = Math.cos(-camera.rotation.y)
    target.z = z
    target.x = x
    target.y = camera.position.y - yaw
    return target
}
document.addEventListener("keydown",(event) => {
    const keyism = event.key.toUpperCase()
    switch (keyism) {
        case "ARROWUP":
            lookHeight += -.1
            lookAt(lookHeight)
            break;
        case "ARROWDOWN":
            lookHeight += .1
            lookAt(lookHeight)
            break;
        case "ARROWRIGHT":
            moveSide(.1)
            break;
        case "ARROWLEFT":
            moveSide(-.1)
    }
})
const maxTurn = Math.PI * 2
const quarterTurn = maxTurn / 4
function moveSide(amt) {
    camera.rotation.set(0,camera.rotation.y,0)
    camera.rotation.y += amt
    //setting the rotation down to 0 when a full turn is completed
    if (Math.abs(camera.rotation.y) >= maxTurn) {
        camera.rotation.y = 0
        console.log("full turn")
    }
    //I'm not sure why I needed to do this but the camera would bounce back and forth without it
    if (Math.abs(camera.rotation.y) >= quarterTurn) {
        console.log("quarter turn")
        camera.rotation.y = -camera.rotation.y + (amt)
    }
    const prevRotation = camera.rotation.y
    lookAt(-lat)
    const same = prevRotation == camera.rotation.y
    if (same) {
        console.log(0)
    } else {
        let diference = prevRotation - camera.rotation.y
        camera.rotation.y += diference
        diference = prevRotation - camera.rotation.y
        console.log("Updated. " + diference)
    }
}```
````

Comment: Using code that you don't understand is a sure fire way to end up with something you don't want and/or something you can't fix. `Three.js` is a huge library -  maybe start at the beginning and work up? As well as this, some comments (they are quite funny) don't line up with the lines of code.